# Stub a service's instance method and check whether it received a call to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rspec, amazon-s3

I'm writing specs for a Rails project that uses an external service (Aws::S3 in this case). I would to stub calls to `upload_file` on any instance of `Aws::S3::Object`, and also be able to check afterwards whether an instance of this class has received a call to `upload_file`.

What I did so far:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Aws::S3::Object).to receive(:upload_file).and_return('Stubbed!')
```

and

```
expect_any_instance_of(Aws::S3::Object).to receive(:upload_file)
```

but somehow the expectation doesn't work (my code calls `upload_file` but RSpec doesn't see it).

Comment: Please share the code that doesn't work.

Comment: I just did. The first snippet works as expected, while the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving forward, I would suggest avoiding the use of `x_any_instance_of` methods for reasons [outlined in the RSpec Mocks documentation](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance).

Instead, stub out the call to `.new` on the `Aws::S3::Object` class, and have an `instance_double` stand in for the actual object that gets initialized in your app so that you can make assertions on it directly.

Here's some example code and specs comparing both syntaxes:

```
module Aws
  module S3
    class Object
      def upload_file
        # upload the file
      end
    end
  end
end

class FileUploader
  def self.upload
    Aws::S3::Object.new.upload_file
  end
end

RSpec.describe FileUploader do
  describe '.upload' do
    context 'using any_instance_of' do
      before do
        allow_any_instance_of(Aws::S3::Object).to receive(:upload_file)
      end

      it 'calls to upload the file on the S3 Object' do
        expect_any_instance_of(Aws::S3::Object).to receive(:upload_file)
        described_class.upload
      end
    end

    context 'using an instance double' do
      let(:s3_object) { instance_double('Aws::S3::Object') }

      context 'stubbing a method to return the double on allow' do
        before do
          allow(Aws::S3::Object).to receive(:new).and_return(s3_object)
        end

        it 'uploads the file on the S3 Object' do
          expect(s3_object).to receive(:upload_file)
          described_class.upload
        end
      end

      context 'stubbing a method to return the double on expect' do
        it 'uploads the file on the S3 Object' do
          expect(Aws::S3::Object).to receive(:new).and_return(s3_object)
          expect(s3_object).to receive(:upload_file)
          described_class.upload
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking of something similar, but is this the preferred way to stub a call to `new`? `x_any_instance_of` was straight-forward, why remove it and not provide an alternative as simple as before?

Comment: For completeness sake, I've added further examples.  As for whether this is the "preferred" way to stub a call to `.new`, I think the only other way to stub a call to new in current RSpec syntax for this case is to have the stub as part of an expectation that returns a mock object (see above examples).  As for why remove it, I'm not a RSpec developer, so I can only point you back to the reasons listed in [the documentation](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance).